# How can the user-agent be changed in Maven?

Tags: maven-2, user-agent

How can I change the user-agent in Maven? I need to be able to change this to get through the company firewall.  I am using version 2.2.1 and I noticed an improvement in the 2.0.10 release notes:

[MNG-3652] - set a user agent for Maven HTTP requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brett Porter posted a blog on [Configuring Maven HTTP Connections](http://brettporter.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/configuring-maven-http-connections/) that describes how you can do this and some other funky things:

```
<server>
  <id>archiva.localhost</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>User-Agent</name>
        <value>Internal-Build-System/1.0</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0):

for command line version
try

```
"-Daether.connector.userAgent=your custom user agent"
```