# Changing User Agent with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven with Java and am trying to parse JSON from Reddit but am getting a response code 492 every time. I need to change the user agent but have no idea how to do this.

I looked at this question: [How can the user-agent be changed in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561658/how-can-the-user-agent-be-changed-in-maven) and the link provided in the answer but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you do anything like that with maven? I mean it's powerful (more powerful than I thought, apparently), but why, instead of hmlunitdriver, httpurlconnection, selenium, etc? Genuine question, I'm curious.

Comment: I'm really just trying to work with and understand maven

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately don't have an answer. But have an upvote.